# Email sent still contains HTML tags.

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I'm sending an email to people using a template. The problem is that all the tags are being shown.

```
<p>Hello,</p>

<p> Please, click the following link to change your password </p>
//...
<p> PLEASE DO NOT REPLY TO THIS MESSAGE</p>
```

The mail received is displaying exactly the original message with all the tags. Is there a way to make it look like

Here's my code:

```
string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/path/myTemplate.txt");
String body;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
   body = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

body = body.Replace("<%PasswordLink%>", pwdLink);

var mail = new MailMessage("from", "to");
mail.Subject = "Password Reset";
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
mail.Body = body;

var client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Host = "123.45.67.89";
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: You gotta do `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to state that the mail message is HTML. If your using [System.Web.Mail.MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) then use:

```
mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
```

If you're using [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) then use:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;`

This will enable HTML formatting for the email.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to define the mail body as HTML:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```